# java code for copying result set into mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

In my java program i want to copy javatable data and copied it in to the mysql table.for that i select one table and select the contents of it then copy.how to copy the result set in to mysql?

Comment: Do you want to store the contents of some Swing JTable into a MySQL table?

Answer (score 0):

`getRowCount()` method returns the number of rows.
`getValueAt(row, col)` returns the data.

```
int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
int columns = jTable1.getColumnCount();

for (int row = 0; row < rows; r++) {
   try {
      rs.moveToInsertRow();

      rs.updateInt("id", Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0));
      rs.updateString("name", jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1));
      rs.updateString("phone", jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2));
      .....

      rs.insertRow();
   } catch (SQLException sqle) {
      ...
   }
}
```

This is a default model sample. Adjust it to your needs:

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {"1", "2", "3"},
        {"4", "5", "6"},
        {"7", "8", "9"},
        {"10", "11", "12"}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"
    }
) {
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
        false, false, false
    };

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit [columnIndex];
    }
});
```